# What is the proper way to clear super-global variable in PHP?

Tags: php, get, reset, superglobals

What is the proper way to clear super-global variable in PHP?

Is this way correct?

```
$_GET = array();
```

Or should I use this way?

```
foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
  unset($_GET[$k]);
}
```

Comment: You don't. Or it would be weird and useless if your try to, because those are automatic created variables, see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Or `unset($_GET);`.  But why?

Comment: FYI, that dupe applies to all superglobals

Comment: Short answer: Both suggested ways should work. Longer answer: Just don't. There must be a better way to solve whatever it is you need to solve.

Comment: @apokryfos Yeah, i think this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: Don't use global variables. Global variables are evil. Save your parse $_GET in your own array use it instead of global var.